# Visual Studio 2015 converting tabs after words into spaces when pasting

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tabs, formatting, spaces

I'm having a formatting issue in Visual Studio 2015 and I can't find the option to fix it. Whenever I paste the code that uses tabs after the initial line indentation, the tabs are converted to spaces and throwing everything off. What is the option to disable this?

Before pasting (Spacing between type and member name is tabs)

```
private int             roomSpacing;
private int             currentLayer;
private int             currentToolIndex;
private int             previousToolIndex;
private TileDrawModes   aboveTileDrawMode;
private TileDrawModes   belowTileDrawMode;
```

After pasting (Everything is spaced now)

```
private int             roomSpacing;
private int             currentLayer;
private int             currentToolIndex;
private int             previousToolIndex;
private TileDrawModes   aboveTileDrawMode;
private TileDrawModes   belowTileDrawMode;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the OP carefully - it is now clear OP is aware of respective settings - this is actually a known issue, also featuring in Visual Studio 2017. Post-code tabs get converted into spaces irrespective of tabs preferences/settings.

As reported by MS: "We recommend that you vote on and follow the earlier reported issue for updates and fix notifications. -- Kevin Pilch, .NET Developer Experience": https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/5873

Answer (score 0):

try Tools-> Options -> Text Editor -> C# -> Tabs -> Keep Tabs

Answer (score 0):

You need to check your editor's settings.

In Visual Studio, go to *Tools -> Options*
Then Choose *Text Editor* and select the Language (let's say C#)
Go to *Formatting* and see if "Automatically format on paste" is checked off. If you turn it off, the editor won't format your code after pasting. You might also want to check the *Spacing* settings under *Formatting* too.
[image]

Comment: I've looked though all of the options in Spacing and nothing looks like it would affect the issue. I would also prefer to keep formatting on pasting.

Comment: what happens if you turn off that flag?

Comment: It doesn't convert them to spaces but it also removes all indentation formatting when pasting from different indentations. Also it requires that I format code manually when pasting from a source with a different coding standard.